# How do I test DataTable fields for NULL in a C# LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a piece of C# LINQ that I'm running against a datatable.
The query is as follows:

```
var results = from myRow in dtDetails.AsEnumerable()
      where
           myRow.Field<DateTime>("ddceffect") > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7)
           && myRow.Field<int>("ddcamtproc") == 0
      select myRow;
```

The field "ddcamrproc" is null.

I getting the following exception:

```
myRow.Field<int>("ddcamtproc")' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
```

How do I alter the LINQ query to test the fields for null before executing the rest of the query?

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Field` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) supports nullable teypes:

```
...   && myRow.Field<int?>("ddcamtproc") == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way as well.

```
var results = dtDetails.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(x => x.ddceffect > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7) && 
                    x.ddcamtproc.HasValue && x.ddcamtproc.Value == 0);
```

OR

```
var results = dtDetails.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(x => x.ddceffect.Substract(DateTime.Today) == -7 
                 && x.ddcamtproc.HasValue && x.ddcamtproc.Value == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since int is derived from system.struct so you need to write int? in Field to `Field<int?>("ddcamtproc") == 0`

Wherever in C# you are using any value type. if that is taking null value you can use nullable types(like int?)